Count years before occurrence on FIRST event
I am working with a longitudinal dataset of districts. blackout indicates whether the district experienced at least one blackout during that year.
df <- data.frame(district= rep(c(1000:1003), each=4),
                 year= rep(c(2000:2003), rep=4),
                 blackout= c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1))

I want to calculate how many years it took for each district to experience their FIRST blackout.
The new df should look like this
df.1 <- data.frame(district= c(1000:1003),
                 time= c(3,5,1,2))

Note how blackouts can be intermittent but I only care for the count of the FIRST year.
Districts that survived the whole period without a blackout should be listed as 5.
Thank you

summarise(df, time = max(cumsum(blackout == 0) * (cummax(blackout) == 0)) + 1, .by = district)

This method will not have trouble with missing or unsorted years.
library(tidyverse)

first_blackout <- df |> 
    filter(blackout == 1) |> 
    summarize(.by = district, first_blackout = min(year))

df |> 
    distinct(district) |> 
    left_join(first_blackout, by = join_by(district)) |> 
    mutate(time = first_blackout - min(df$year) + 1,
           time = replace_na(time, 5))



summarise(df, time=case_when(
  all(blackout==0)~5,
  all(blackout==1)~1,
  .default=1 + min(year[blackout==1]) - min(year[blackout==0])), .by=district)


  district time
1     1000    3
2     1001    5
3     1002    1
4     1003    2


You can summarize it by finding out the min position of row in blackout that equals 1 per district. If every blackout is zero, set it to 5 using ifelse.
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  summarize(time = ifelse(all(blackout == 0), 5, min(which(blackout == 1))), 
            .by = district)

  district time
1     1000    3
2     1001    5
3     1002    1
4     1003    2


This requires the data be sorted by year and not have any missing years.

With by:
by(df, ~district, \(d) with(d, {
  j = suppressWarnings(min(which(blackout==1L))) 
  if(is.finite(j)) year[j]-year[1L]+1L else length(year)+1L })) |> 
  array2DF()


or
tapply(df$blackout, df$district, \(x) max(cumsum(x==0L)*(cummax(x)==0L))+1L))

which borrows the logic given by user @M-- Save the Data Dump in the comment below your question. Gives
  district Value
1     1000     3
2     1001     5
3     1002     1
4     1003     2

